# Unable to add Disk or FileShare Quorum Witness to Mirrored Storage Spaces Direct Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, windows-cluster, storage-spaces-direct

So as the title states I am unable to add a Quorum Witness to my cluster with the two options that do not involve azure.

I've tried several different commands for the disk witness as you can see it is disk number 9.
[image: cluster disks view]

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2'
Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening resource 'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'pacQuorumVol'
Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening resource 'pacQuorumVol'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'pacQuorumVol'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'Cluster Disk 9'
Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening resource 'Cluster Disk 9'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority 'Cluster Disk 9'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority '\\?\Volume{17A6910F-44F6-4A28-BB2F-EA2CBADE25C4}\'
Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening resource '\\?\Volume{17A6910F-44F6-4A28-BB2F-EA2CBADE25C4}\'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndDiskMajority '\\?\Volume{17A6910F-44F6-4A28 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand
```

Every time I get the error that it can not open the resource.
So I moved on to a file share witness. I have a synology rackstation and created an SMB share on it. I gave this share every possible permission, but get a code 67 every time I try to add it. This is so frustrating :(

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndFileShareMajority "\\corpnas1\pacClusterQuorom"
Set-ClusterQuorum : There was an error configuring the file share witness '\\corpnas1\pacClusterQuorom'.
    There was an error granting the cluster access to the selected file share '\\corpnas1\pacClusterQuorom'
    Method failed with unexpected error code 67.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ClusterQuorum -NodeAndFileShareMajority "\\hostname\pacClusterQuo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumComman
```

I thought I could add a physical disk in a machine and use that as the disk witness, but it seems like that isn't the case. If it is, I can't find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same but via GUI? Right click on cluster name -> More Actions -> Configure Cluster Quorum Settings -> and select disk quorum resources. Also, did you get any errors in Cluster events? If so, could you please share them?

Comment: Yes I tried it in the GUI and it says under 'Configure a disk witness' that 'No quorum witness has been configured for the cluster.'. I tried 'Configure a file share witness' and got the same error as I did on the command line. The only errors in the log are about the files disappearing for a test vm I created and the vm role failing and the vm unable to start since the files were gone. I was thinking this was because I shut down one of the nodes and had a split-brain condition that caused corruption since I didn't have quorum.

Comment: The split brain can be caused by the S2D because of metadata is not flushed to the disks before shutting down... I've faced it previously. We've switched S2D to other SDS solution and works just perfectly...

Comment: @Strepsils Thank you for your input. I was hoping a quorum witness would solve this.

Comment: The quorum witness needed only as the additional vote in the cluster. It is very weird that you cannot configure at least file share witness. We are using starwind vsan in 2 nodes hyper-converged scenario and everything working just great with disk witness and cluster shared volumes...

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue - what account do you use to manage the cluster? I have some clients running 2-nodes cluster on a top of StarWind VSAN and never seen this issue. You can try it to create the quorum disk, they have a free version.

Comment: I'm trying StarWind VSAN now to see if I still have the quorum issue.